# How to replace multiple strings in a file that are both lowercase as well as capitalized?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read and replace all occurring strings within a file. Most are lowercase but there is one that is capitalized. How to a read the file so that regardless of the capitalization all strings are removed.

For reference this is the text I would like to edit and the word I would like to replace is "morning/Morning".

**Text below**:

"Good morning! / I was going to say you good morning / Good Afternoon Morning is when the sun comes up / I will call you in the morning"

**See code below:**

```
filename = input("Enter the filename: ")
stringToRemove = input("Enter the string to be removed: ")
infile = open(filename, 'r')
fileString = infile.read()
fileString = fileString.replace(stringToRemove, '')
infile.close()

outfile = open(filename, 'w')
outfile.write(fileString)
outfile.close()

print("Done")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `re.sub` in case insensitive mode:

```py
filename = input("Enter the filename: ")
stringToRemove = input("Enter the string to be removed: ")
infile = open(filename, 'r')
fileString = infile.read()
fileString = re.sub(r'\s*' + stringToRemove + r'\s*', ' ', fileString, flags=re.IGNORECASE).strip()
```

The output from your sample string here would be:

> Good ! / I was going to say you good / Good Afternoon is when the sun comes up / I will call you in the